# How can I specify the order of results within groups when querying Derby?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, derby

I am using a Derby database.

I have a table like this:

```
TB_ORDERS
BUYER_NAME  DATE_CREATED    OTHER_COLLUMS ......
---------------------------------------------
 DAVID       2012-09-01         ----
 PETER       2012-09-14         ----
 DAVID       2012-09-05         ----
 PETER       2012-09-02         ----
 DAVID       2012-08-15         ----
 MARY        2012-09-02         ----
 MARY        2012-09-15         ----
```

I am trying to get a result grouped by BUYER_NAME where each group should be ordered by DATE_CREATED and finally everything ordered by the group's most recent date, like this:

```
MARY    2012-09-15
MARY    2012-09-12
PETER   2012-09-14
PETER   2012-09-02
DAVID   2012-09-05
DAVID   2012-09-01
DAVID   2012-08-15
```

As you can see, the Mary's Group has the most recent date_created so it is placed on top. 
Then we get Peter's group on second place (note that Peter's group has a date "09-14" higher then one date on Mary's group "09-12" however, Peter's group is placed after Mary's group as every thing should be ordered by the group's most recent date.

I have tried every thing I know with no success. The closest I got was:

```
Select date_created, buyer_name 
From ORDERS 
Order By buyer_name,date_created Desc;
```

However, the groups are not ordered by the most recent group date.

Should I do that in my code or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will bring you the most recent date_created of each buyer_name, together with the result set that you already had. If you include this new column in your Order By clause it should do the trick:

```
Select o.date_created, o.buyer_name,
       (select max(date_created) from orders where buyer_name = o.buyer_name) as most_recent_date
From ORDERS o
Order By most_recent_date, o.buyer_name, o.date_created Desc
```

Comment: Thank you Henrique for such an elegant solution!!

Comment: Welcome. If it really helped you, you can always select it as the correct answer by clicking on the tick under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Henrique, thank you for such an elegant solution. I have tried for at least 3 days before posting the problem.

Now, I've got a new one. When I try to paginate the query for 3 itens per page, I get Petter in the first page and again in the second page. To solve this problem I am using a subquery where I select all distinct date_created grouped by buyers, and that is where I do my pagination. It works. However, it is not elegant and efficient like yours. 
This is my poor solution (I've added a new line "WHERE"):

```
Select o.date_created, o.buyer_name,
    (select max(date_created) from orders where buyer_name = o.buyer_name) as most_recent_date
From ORDERS o  
    where buyer_name in (SELECT buyer_name FROM ORDERS  WHERE date_created in (SELECT  MAX(date_created)  FROM ORDERS GROUP BY buyer_name ORDER BY 1 DESC OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY))
Order By  most_recent_date, o.buyer_name, o.date_created ASC

PS: the resultset shows the oldest date first and for that I am using a
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Knowledge is good but imagination is better.

Tks again for your time, Armando